# Array filtered with another array (CS and Predicate)

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, nspredicate, case-sensitive

The following code print the line below:

```
TestApp[1156:207] Array: (
    "Type A"
)
```

But isn't right. The `NSPredicate` should ignore the case sensitive.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[TestObject alloc] initWithType:@"Type A"],
                                                      [[TestObject alloc] initWithType:@"Type B"],
                                                      [[TestObject alloc] initWithType:@"Type C"],
                                                      [[TestObject alloc] initWithType:@"Type D"],
                                                      [[TestObject alloc] initWithType:@"Type E"], nil];

    NSArray *filter = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Type A", @"Type d", nil];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF.type IN[cd] %@", filter];

    NSLog(@"Array: %@", [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The similar issue was raised in this thread: [Case insensitive NSPredicate for strings from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016997/case-insensitive-nspredicate-for-strings-from-an-array)

It seems that IN does not support [c] modifier.
Solution for your case is to change the query, e.g. to use CONTAINS.

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY %@ CONTAINS[cd] SELF.type", filter]`