# Can NSPredicate use case insensitive search with Core Data IN comparison? (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

In my case I have an object in Core Data with an id field which is a String. The field is populated by several clients on different platforms, and is supposed to be a GUID/UUID. Ideally these should always be upper case, but not all client implementations do that, and the code for storing them did not take care of that. Let's ignore the obvious architecture mistake for now. What I need is a way to search for these in a case insensitive way. For I now simply fetch all from storage, and then filter them using the Swift array filter function. This works, but is ineffective, and when the dataset gets large, it will require a lot of RAM. I tried using a predicate like

`fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "someId IN [cd] %@", ids)`

Where ids is an array of String. This doesn't work. Could it be solved using predicate with block? Any other solutions?

Comment: I am afraid that you are out of luck here, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/2017805/1187415 (possible duplicate?) And a block-based predicate cannot be used with a Core Data fetch request. – As you said, normalizing the data in the database would be the proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Martin R for your comment, it led me to the solution that worked for me. I ended up with this solution. It's not quite what I wanted, but knowing that the ids array would rarely have more than 10 entries, it will do for now as it at least solves the memory problem. Hopefully Swift and Core Data will provide a better solution in the future.

```
var predicates = [NSPredicate]()

for id in idList
{
     predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "temporaryId LIKE[c] %@", id))
}

fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
```

Comment: Using string interpolation for building predicates is error-prone and dangerous. If  `id` happens to contain a special character (e.g. quotation mark) then this can crash.  Better have a look as NSCompoundPredicate to build your “OR predicate” dynamically.

Comment: I've changed my solution as you recommended Martin. Seems to work fine. Thank you for your time, if you see anything else I should change, I'll be grateful for any further help :)